# Embedding image that requires authentication in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I would like to put images by their URL into TinyMCE.
I have the Rich Text Editor on a different domain than the webapp containing the images.
User needs to be authenticated to get these images.

I have that problem partially solved for readonly situation using `Blob` and `URL.createObjectURL`

Problem with RTE is that <img> tag is altered to <img src="blob:hostname/hash"/>. This link works on a single machine as long as the tab that created the `ObjectURL` is open.

For editing purposes I have to display these images as blob in RTE, but to save them with their proper url address.

Is there a way to achieve this in TinyMCE in any way?

Comment: I am not familiar with TinyMCE, but cant you use base64 instead of the blob?

Comment: I can do either. However, if possible, I don't want base64 image to be saved as the content. I need the src="/link/to/the/picture"